# How to show only homepage in google results instead of privacy, contact pages

Tags: posts, pages, search, homepage, google

When I search my website in google, all the pages and posts can see. I want to make only homepage visible in search results and remove other pages(privacy, contact etc). And also all the posts can visible without snippet. I want to fix this. Please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua5PU.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your WP directory edit ( or create ) robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$ 
Disallow: /
```

Then wait till search engine reindex your pages, or try to run it manually with google with Google Search Console

Comment: Thank you very much.